# What is the best Horde PvP support race/class in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I typically play a support role in most MMOs:

```
 Combat Medic - Star Wars Galaxies
 White Mage and Red Mage - Final Fantasy XI
```

I'm going to be playing with a few friends (I've been playing druid and paladin already in WoW, and like them both) on a PvP server, and need to know what class would be best all-around for generally staying alive while still being as close as possible to a healer/support class.  I also don't want to stand around looking for a party, so a high-demand class would be best.

I know you can change races now for a fee, but you get bonus points for suggesting the best Horde race to go along with the class.

You get double bonus points for suggesting the best crafting jobs to go along with your race/class suggestion.  :)

Thanks!

```
 (I have all current expansions, so all races/classes are free game)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a restoration (healing) spec.  The classes capable of healing are druid, monk, paladin, priest, and shaman.  Racially there aren't a lot of significant differences, though specific races can only play certain classes.  (Alliance races are listed below as well, though the original question was about Horde)

- Druid (*Horde: tauren, troll; Alliance: night elf, worgen*) - limited to leather armor; tree form (cooldown ability) increases healing throughput; good profession choices: skinning/leatherworking, herbalism/(inscription or alchemy), mining/jewelcrafting
- Monk (*any except  Horde: goblin; Alliance: worgen*) - limited to leather armor; use brews and teas as the primary basis of skills; similar professions to druid (I've never played a monk healer, so can't really address the specifics...)
- Paladin (*Horde: blood elf, tauren; Alliance: draenei, dwarf, human*) - can train to use plate armor at level 40(?), limited to mail previously; some people think they are limited to single-target (tank) healing, but do have some raid utility too; professions: any of the combinations mentioned above, or mining/blacksmithing
- Priest (*Horde: any except orc; Alliance: any*) - limited to cloth armor; best professions: tailoring/enchanting or herbalism/alchemy
- Shaman (*Horde: goblin, orc, pandaren, tauren, troll; Alliance: draenei, dwarf, pandaren*) - can train to use mail armor at level 40, limited to leather previously; can also use shields; in addition to direct healing spells, also have totems that provide passive effects and healing; professions: similar to paladin

For all, you can learn first aid, cooking and fishing as secondary professions that will come in handy.

Note that resto is much easier to level as primary spec now that you get access to the LFD tool at level 15.  And, they're in big enough demand that you shouldn't normally have queue times that are very long.

**ETA: Cataclysm/Mists updates**

Answer (score 1):

All the healing classes are pretty well needed. Shaman atm isn't quite as nice a class as the ones galactic mentioned but it gets an ability (bloodlust) that is basically required in every raid. It depends on your server what class is more in demand. As well, if you intend to do a lot of pve and pvp then druid might be best. They are great pvp healers and amazing at survival. As well they are useful for raid healing in pve. And you can play as a tanking class as well if it is needed.